# How to configure cors in Azure portal

Tags: azure, cors, config, azureportal

I tried to configure cors in Azure portal.

I set allowed origins as "https://fott.azurewebsites.net".(I get this URL from OPTION request's Origin field).
I also set allowed methods as "GET".

[CORS Setting Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAApM.png)

I thought that this setting is enough but it still retrieves 403 error.

"403 CORS not enabled or no matching rule found for this request."

Is there any other things to config for CORS?

Comment: *Is there any other things to config for CORS?* There's no one way to configure CORS. You need to tell us what kind of request (HTTP method, headers, etc.) you're sending to the server.

Comment: @jub0bs.
Here's the request.
GET https://****************.blob.core.windows.net/**************?sp=r&st=2022-02-25T01:37:34Z&se=2022-02-25T09:37:34Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=Cjjr2x2kHKn%2BhcI24D4O4CW%2FQprEnKPKOWlX9gHZ1vo%3D&prefix=&delimiter=%2F&restype=container&comp=list&_=1645755497560
headers
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-ms-client-request-id,x-ms-version
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Host: *****************.blob.core.windows.net
Origin: https://fott.azurewebsites.net
Referer: https://fott.azurewebsites.net/
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Thanks

Comment: check this post:

https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2018/09/12/authorization-header-and-cors/

Authorization must be on for some http verbs over CORS.

Answer (score 0):

As per our observations, you have missed enabling the `Allowed Headers` option. That could be the reason why you are getting a `403` error.

[image]

In place of allowed headers use `"x-ms-*"`which will allow all the site permissions. And in place of Exposed headers use `"x-ms-content length"`

Also, you can enable cors policy using CLI command

```sh
$ctx=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "clouXXXXXXXman" -StorageAccountKey "ExXXXXXXXXXzUgkXi80HHrXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$CorsRules = (@{
AllowedHeaders=@("x-ms-blob-content-type","x-ms-blob-content-disposition");
AllowedOrigins=@("*");
MaxAgeInSeconds=30;
AllowedMethods=@("Get","Connect")},
@{
AllowedOrigins=@("http://www.fabrikam.com","http://www.contoso.com");
ExposedHeaders=@("x-ms-meta-data*","x-ms-meta-customheader");
AllowedHeaders=@("x-ms-meta-target*","x-ms-meta-customheader");
MaxAgeInSeconds=30;
AllowedMethods=@("Put")})
Set-AzStorageCORSRule -ServiceType Blob -CorsRules $CorsRules -Context $ctx
```

below is the reference links for complete information about cors policy

1. [Enabling cors policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/cross-origin-resource-sharing--cors--support-for-the-azure-storage-services#enabling-cors-for-azure-storage).
2. [Get Blob (REST API) - Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob)

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.
I've tried to add allowed header as "x-ms-*".
But it still doesn't work properly. I appreciate your effort and please have a look at it once more.

Comment: have you tried adding it through command let